# invalid use of brace-enclosed initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I want to initialize the Foo class

```
class Foo {
public:
    struct MyStruct {
        uint8 i;
        char c;
    };

    Foo(MyStruct args...){

    };
};
```

But I'm getting a error

> error: invalid use of brace-enclosed initializer list

```
auto test = Foo(
    {1, 'a'},
    {2, 'b'}
);
```

If I do this with variables, there is no error

```
Foo::MyStruct a1 = {1, 'a'};
Foo::MyStruct b2 = {2, 'b'};

auto test = Foo(a1, b2);
```

But I'm not comfortable with that, I'd like to make the code a compact

Comment: What is `MyStruct args...`?

Comment: Note `Foo(MyStruct args...)` is not a C++-style variadic function taking zero or more `MyStruct` arguments. It's a C-style variadic function taking one `MyStruct` and then any list of following arguments, which can only be accessed using `va_arg`.

Comment: No time for a proper answer right now, but you appear to want `Foo(std::initializer_list<MyStruct> args);`.

Comment: Why did you tag this as `initializer-list` when you're not using one..?

Comment: @underscore_d It was an edit.

Comment: @aschepler I'm using microcontroller, I don't have the resources to use std

Comment: @Fulrus In that case it is unclear what you are asking. Please edit your question to include the relevant information. Or consider posting another one.

Comment: @Fulrus What kind of "resources" do you believe `std::initializer_list` uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly state the types you're passing onto the constructor. The following compiles:

```
auto test = Foo(
  Foo::MyStruct{1, 'a'},
  Foo::MyStruct{2, 'b'}
);
```

Note aschepler's comment though that `Foo(MyStruct args...)` is not a C++-style variadic function. So you might be in trouble if you're actually going to try and do something with the constructor arguments. In other words: you will get in trouble :).

Comment: If the constructor explicitly took a container of `MyStruct`, they would not need to specify the type for any element.